# Voltage Conversion from 220V to 5V

Tags: analog

I want to convert 220 V ac to 5 V ac, and then fed that scaled ac to A/D converter.I don't want to use transformers.
How good it is to use OPAMP as inverting amplifier or voltage divider.?
I simulated the circuit in LTSpice by using LT1006 ,apparently there is no problem.
I also used Voltage divider and buffer combination,that also worked good in simulation.
Kindly suggest me the best and small circuit that has little problem associated with it.[image]

[image]

Comment: If you ever end up using resistors on the 220V AC side, remember putting a few in series to stack up their voltage rating.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a design service.

Comment: According to the pic, L should be connected to R1 and N should be connected to R2. What if the connection is reversed? Have you ever thought about this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a transformer?

Comment: @RohatKılıç ,@ThreePhaseEel ,I haven't considered that,I am not good at electronics. Do you mean transformer with N. I will modify my circuit by inserting  inductor. I am trying to consider transformer as final option, because the PCB will be bulky. Please tell me if possible with any other option. I also tried the above circuit available at some forum,but that one have too much noise due to switching.

Comment: http://microcontrollerslab.com/ac-voltage-measurement-using-microcontroller/

Comment: @ahmad What I'm trying to say is this: Just look at your schematic. (+) terminal of V1 is LINE (L) and (-) terminal of V1 is NEUTRAL (N). Actually, this circuit can work as expected; but can you guarantee that this circuit will always be connected in that way? Because reverse connection can lead to something horrible.

Comment: @RohatKılıç ,I am afraid this wont work like this always, reverse connection can cause trouble,In order to avoid that i tried to use differential amplifier,but LM358 give me too much noise. Now i am looking for some other way,if found nothing then certainly will come to transformer.

Comment: @ahmad _"... I am not good at electronics ..."_ - Then please don't mess with mains voltage. A simple misunderstanding could kill you, or someone else.

Answer (score 3):

The best circuit to use is a small transformer, as it has isolation between the mains supply and you.

How about simply a resistive voltage divider? It has the benefit of simplicity, a reasonably low output impedance to drive the ADC, and a well specified and calculable input voltage withstanding, if you read the data sheets for the components you use.

You could put an LT1006 after the voltage divider if you want to. It depends what your ADC input looks like, whether it needs a lower impedance than is feasible with a resistive divider.

Comment: Check this pic, i passed it from buffer, simulation is giving me good result.

Comment: +1 for the transformer otherwise the whole thing is floating on the mains, they are not to disciplined over what is N and what is L where we are.

Comment: @RoyC If not any other method is applicable then i would definitely consider transformer.

Comment: Its not a matter of methods being available, its a matter of SAFETY, connecting things directly to a mains supply is dangerous unless you throughly understand all of the problems and risks.

Comment: Thanks @RoyC, It better to use transformer, Now i am considering to use PT(potential Transformer) like this small model available ZMPT107. Hope it will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

What are you going to do with the 5V AC output? If you are just going to compute peak or RMS amplitude, phase angle, etc and do not mind some crossover distortion, you could use two optoisolators as shown below. Optoisolators provide the electrical isolation like a transformer, but are much smaller and a tiny fraction of the weight.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Vince Patron, I got this idea from you, i will try to simulate it and learn little about it.

Comment: ,Currently i am only considering peak but in future i want to make my circuit capable of power factor correction ,that's why i don't want to use a circuit that add phase shift in the sensed input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interface opamps with high voltages and don't want to use a transformer, Norton Amplifiers are an alternative to using a voltage divider.

They work with currents instead of voltages at the inputs, so you can feed the high voltage directly to the input using a high ohm resistor.

The kind of old LM3900 is such an amplifier. You'll find examples in the application note for the chip, chapter 10.12:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa653/snoa653.pdf

More modern versions of this amplifier architecture are available, mostly build to be used as video amplifiers, but the same principle as the schematics for the LM3900 apply to them.

Comment: Thanks @Nils .I will look for its spice model and will see if it works, but as Roy says i should consider transformer now.